# Updating many rows from a hash without just looping in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a hash which has in excess of a thousand key/value pairs.

I have a database table with several thousand rows.

So to brute-force an update of the table based on the hash is pretty simple. e.g. :

```
my_hash.each{|key,value|
   Model.update_all("column2 = #{value}", "column1 = #{key}")
}
```

But this will do over a thousand SQL update statements.

Is there any good way (in Rails) to do this with one (or just a few) update statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I have solved this with the hints from Mike Woodhouse and ttarchala. Here's the code (I am using the [Ruby Sequel gem](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/))

```
# connect to the database
DB = Sequel.connect("postgres://user:password@localhost/blah")

# create the temporary table
DB.create_table :temp_update, :temp => true do
  primary_key :key
  String :value
end

# insert rows from the hash (multi_insert takes an array of hashes,hence the map)
DB[:temp_update].multi_insert(my_hash.map{|k,v| {:key => k, :value => v}})

# Do the update based on a join
DB.execute("  UPDATE my_table 
              SET column2 = temp_update.value 
              FROM temp_update
              WHERE column1 = temp_update.id")
```

I am using Postgres, so the exact update SQL may be different for other RDBMSs.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way -- in any language, don't know how it's done in Rails specifically -- will be to dump your in-memory hash into a temporary table in the database, which only has columns for your hash's keys and values, then issue a single UPDATE command with a join that links your table to be updated with the new temp table.

Check the query plan to ensure that the optimizer works as it should, building a temporary index on your temp table before issuing the update. If it doesn't, build the index yourself.

Comment: +1, however, this will only work if you can load your hash table more quickly than you can run the update

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of this method, but not sure how do it in Rails :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about "good", but on many DBMS platforms it's possible to send multiple SQL statements in a single execution. The [ar-extensions](http://www.continuousthinking.com/tags/arext) gem, for example, can help to batch INSERT statements, although depending on platform it may need a little tweaking - Oracle, for example, is a little tricky. I don't think it handles UPDATEs directly, but you could look into using the temp table trick from another answer here: batch load the data and run an UPDATE using `ActiveRecord.execute`.

Possibly only "good" in the sense that it's probably possible, but then again, Rails (or more accurately ActiveRecord) never intended that the ORM functions be used for absolutely *everything*, that's why things like `find_by_sql` exist: they're there for the times when you know a better way.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. I don't know specifically about rails, but you can use the IN sql keyword, which works like:

```
select * from table where column in ('list', 'of', 'values')
```

Comment: I'll help him out: UPDATE table SET field=value , field2=value2 WHERE id in (3,8,33,756,6543,54637)